# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector: Class Loader Not Found

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Using Confluent Docker all in one package with tag 5.4.1; I am struggling to get a jdbc sink connector up and running.

When I launch the following connector:

```json
{
  "name": "mySink",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "topics": [
    "myTopic"
  ],
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver:1433;databaseName=myDB",
  "connection.user": "user",
  "connection.password": "**********",
  "dialect.name": "SqlServerDatabaseDialect",
  "insert.mode": "insert",
  "table.name.format": "TableSink",
  "pk.mode": "kafka",
  "fields.whitelist": [
    "offset",
    "value"
  ],
  "auto.create": "true"
}
```

*(Some attributes edited)*

I get the following exception on from the connect container:
`ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' was not found.`

I have the following environment variable for connect:
`CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"`

And if I check in the container I have:
`/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`

With the following files:

```
./jtds-1.3.1.jar
./common-utils-5.4.0.jar
./slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
./kafka-connect-jdbc-5.4.0.jar
./postgresql-9.4.1212.jar
./sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar
./mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar
./mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre13.jar
./mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre11.jar
```

The only changes I have made from the base connect image are the mssql jdbc drivers. These are working fine for a jdbc source connector.

Extra information as requested:
Output from `curl -s localhost:8083/connector-plugins|jq '.[].class'`

```
"io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector"
"io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector"
"io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector"
"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector"
"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector"
"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector"
"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector"
"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector"
```

docker-compose from:
https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/5.4.1-post/cp-all-in-one

Images:

```
confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.4.1                 
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.4.1
confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.4.1              
cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.2.0-5.4.0
confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.4.1               
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.1          
confluentinc/cp-server:5.4.1                   
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.1
```

Comment: Which docker image are you using? and can you edit your question to include the output of `curl -s localhost:8083/connector-plugins|jq '.[].class'`

Comment: @Robin Extra information added on images and connector plugins.

Comment: "The only changes I have made from the base connect image are the mssql jdbc drivers." - how are you making these changes?

Comment: also how are you launching the connector? are you using `curl`

Comment: Connector is being launched from Confluent Control Center. The mssql jdbc drivers are mounted from the host into /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc.

Comment: Does it work if you post the REST call directly to the worker using `curl` ?

Comment: @Robin Thanks for your pointers. I have the connector creating now posting directly to the REST API. It still has an error, but not class loader related, looks like serialization. I am reading https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/ to resolve :). I will post steps I took as an answer here once I have it fully up and running.

Comment: FYI, do not add jre11, jre13, and jre8 drivers onto the same classpath

Comment: @cricket_007 I think this was part of my issue. I was mounting the folder from the mssql jdbc distro with multiple jars and some other stuff into the container in /kafka-connect-jdbc. I changed this to just the .jar files and the class loader went away but I got errors associated with an incorrect runtime. I resolved this by just using the jre8 version. But as others have found I had to get that file into /usr/share/java/kafka as well.

Comment: You only need one folder, and it should be [under kafka-connect-jdbc](https://github.com/cricket007/kafka-connect-sandbox/blob/master/connect-compose.yml#L97) ... Multiple blog posts and Youtubes and conference talks have already been given about this